# What happened to the Expand / Collapse folder function in Files (Nautilus) 43.0?

Tags: nautilus, 22.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 from 22.04, I noticed that the *expand / collapse folder function* in Files (Nautilus) is gone together with the small triangle preceding the folder name!

Similarly, the keyboard shortcuts "expand folder" (`→` / right arrow key) and "collapse folder" (`←` / left arrow key), *although documented* (in the **Keyboard Shortcuts** dialog's 2nd tab), do not work!

Is there any action that will restore this functionality? Nothing is present in the **Preferences** dialog which becomes more crippled with every new version of Nautilus. And, I have also looked at the `dconf-editor` **/ org / gnome / nautilus** path: The **list-view / use-tree-view** option has no effect.

---

The old version of Files (42.2) in Ubuntu 22.04:

[image: Files in 22.04]

---

The new version of Files (43.0) in Ubuntu 22.10:

[image: Files in 22.10]

Comment: Another option that is missing is to share a folder (via Samba), the hole settings menu is simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the feature is not anymore available in Files 43 that comes with Ubuntu 22.10. That is related to the move from GTK3 to GTK4: attempts to re-implement [were not ready](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/merge_requests/817#note_1522493). Hopefully it will be back in a later version.

Comment: Then I will have to switch from "normal" to "lts" upgrades. :(