# How to sort list created by "Expandable Folders in List View"?

Tags: nautilus, file-sorting

I've recently discovered this feature, and I love it; however, the created list is sorted by modification date, rather then name. Looking at nautilus' settings in dconf (`~ / list-view / default-column-order`), sorting by name should be the default.

I did come across [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436622/what-happened-to-the-expand-collapse-folder-function-in-files-nautilus-43-0) saying that this feature as whole wasn't ready for the switch from GTK3 - GTK4, perhaps this is related?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple; you have use a 'Custom value' in `dconf` with `['name']` (or whatever you want) as the only option, delete everything else in the text box.